# How to make a div appear partially overlayed on top of another square div

Tags: php, javascript, css

I am trying to code this from scratch, so that when a button clicked it makes an options div appear on top of the existing div without displacing it's original position. This picture illustrates the concept:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxL4r.jpg

I have put an 'onclick' command on the button so that the javascript below is executed upon clicking the button

```
xmlObj.open ('GET', '/ajax?action=editbox', true);
xmlObj.send ('');
```

I have omitted the rest of the code prior to this point as it's standard stuff.

This is where I am now completely stuck. I want to now have code in a php file called 'editbox.php' which tells the webpage to make the options div in the picture appear on top of the orignal div (without displacing the position of the original div).

I would appreciate any tips or guidance very much.

Comment: Just to be clear is it the css to position the div that is giving you trouble or the the php script to send a response to the ajax call?

Comment: Hi Jrod. Both of those parts are what I don't know how to do. RwL below has kindly written out how to do the CSS part I think, I am checking it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like more of an HTML/CSS question; there's no clear reason (at least, not from the phrasing of the question) to use PHP to accomplish this. Your options div might as well be present in the DOM from the time your page is first loaded, but with its CSS `display` set to `none`. Give the button and the parent div `position: relative` then style the button and the options div to be positioned absolutely to the upper right corner of the parent. Make sure the button and the options div are the last children of that parent box, and that they're in that order, so the z-index will naturally occur the way you want them to. In the button's `onclick`, set the options div to `display: block`.

Comment: With that approach though, if I click the button and the options div is displayed, will clicking it again hide the options div?

Comment: With the approach I described, the button would be covered up by the options div -- so I'd expect that you'd add a close button to the options, or a save button that in addition to saving the options would hide the div, revealing the button again. If you want the button to stay on top the whole time, you can just reverse the source order of the button and the options div in the original markup. Then you'd modify your clickhandler on the button to simple "if options div is visible, hide it, if not, show it" logic.

Comment: Hello, I followed your guidance and put a button which opens and closes the div which works fine. The only problem is the button moves after I click it to open the div. I don't understand what you mean by reversing the source order of the button and the options div in the markup to fix this, could you please explain.

Comment: The button moves where? If it's absolutely positioned to the top right of the parent, then it should stay put. I'd need to see the page (or at least all the relevant code pasted into jsfiddle.net to really be of much more help.

Comment: I follow your instructions and if I specify the style of the child div as style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0; " relative to the parent it doesn't move. But I actually need it top:10 and right:15, and when I specify it absolutely with these paramaters it moves. Can you please explain how to resolve this and then I am done!

Comment: Are you literally setting top: 10 and right: 15 without 'px'? You need to specify a unit for non-zero values. That might be your issue there.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was the answer! That was silly of me. Great. I've chosen your answer, thanks for all the assistance I would have been stumped for days otherwise.